# Restaurar un registro de la base de datos Mysql

Tags: mysql, python, django

Trabajo con una base de datos `MySQL` (`python/django`).

Eliminé algunos registros de una clase y necesito recuperarlos.

Tengo un `Backup` de la base de datos con el formato sql.
Me supieron decir que puedo recuperar algunos registros teniendo ese `Backup`.

**¿Como se hace eso?**

Sería mantener mi base de datos actual y agregar esos registros de la base de datos anterior.

Cuando quiero toda la base de datos localmente, ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
python manage.py dbshell > labasededatos.sql
```

Pero ahora no quiero eso.

Comment: saludos te sugiero revisar: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14359/how-can-i-restore-a-single-record-from-a-mysql-backup-file

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero restaurar tu `DB` y después usar [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) o tu propio script para exportar y posterior carga de datos

por ejemplo si el modelo que quieres restaurar la información es `MyModel` usa:

```
python manage.py dumpdata myapp.MyModel > backup.json
```

posteriormente lo puedes cargar con:

```
manage.py loaddata backup.json
```

También puedes hacer un script para exportar.

```
from django.core import serializers
from myproject.myapp import models
data = serializers.serialize("json", models.MyModel.objects.all())
with open("mymodel.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```